# Get string truncated to max length

Tags: c#, strings, extension-methods

This is an extension method to get a string that is truncated to a maximum length.

Any comments?

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string WithMaxLength(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that's pretty much as good as it gets. There isn't much to say about this few code.

Comment: Isn't it a bit inconsistent that `WithMaxLength(null, 1)` doesn't throw an exeption whereas `WithMaxLength("", 1)` would?

Comment: @KonradMorawski neither would throw an exception. WithMaxLength(null, 1) would return null and WithMaxLength("", 1) would return ""...

Comment: @Jakob eh, you're correct of course, what I actually meant was `WithMaxLength(null, -1)` vs. `WithMaxLength("", -1)`

Comment: @KonradMorawski that's true, nice remark. If you feel as if the function should do this better you could write an answer with a better version?

Comment: @Jakob I wasn't sure if it's worth of posting a separate answer, but sure, an answer added :)

Comment: For what purpose do you truncate? How do you define length? Which kind of sequences do you want to keep intact (e.g. code-points or even text-elements)?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have a legacy system where settings for actions are stored in a table with a long description. Then when a action is performed the description is saved in several places with different maximum lengths in the database and I just want to save what is room for and discard the rest.

Comment: @Jakob Are those other places all using UTF-16 and set their length limit in UTF-16 code-units?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have not thought about encodings, this is used internally where all machines have the same encoding so it has not been a problem for me. They just use the default encoding...

Comment: With default encoding you mean windows-1252? So you can only represent western european characters and corrupt any other unicode code-points?

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes that is correct. Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: Remember, this an EXTENSION, checking for null is useless (You can't do: null.WithMaxLength(1) ). That will always trigger a NullReferenceException!

Comment: Remember, extension methods don't *have to* be invoked against an instance: `StringExtensions.WithMaxLength(maybeNull)` is a perfectly legal invocation too.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're using C# 6.0, I believe you can drop the null-check:

```
public static string WithMaxLength(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    return value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));
}
```

Other than that, it's like [Jeroen said](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101017/get-string-with-max-length#comment184636_101017): *that's pretty much as good as it gets*.

The class and parameter naming is exactly as I'd have it, and the name of the extension method is decent, although I'd try to find a name that better indicates that *truncation will occur* when `value` is longer than `maxLength`... but `WithMaxLength` isn't a bad name.

Comment: I agree with you regarding naming.  The method truncates a string, if needed, and the naming should reflect that.  If I were to use something named `WithMaxLength`, I might expect the returned to string to actually have `maxLength` even if I pass string.Empty as the input `value`.

Comment: "Keep" or "Left" are common names for such a method.

Comment: The function allows negative values for maxLength, which is unhandled and produces unexpected results (same issue as for the code provided by the question).

Comment: Using the C# 8 range .. operator: `=> value?[..Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength)];`

Answer (score 12):

There is an inconsistency - negative values of `maxLength` would be forgiven for `value` being `null`, but cause an exception for every other input (since `Substring` would throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`).

There's two possible approaches that remove this inconsistency - fail fast

```
public static string WithMaxLength(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    if (maxLength < 0)
    {
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxLength must be equal to or greater than 0");
    }
    // ...
```

Or ignore negative values for both cases:

```
public static string WithMaxLength(this string value, int maxLength)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (maxLength < 0)
    {
        return "";
    }
    return value.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));
}
```

Personally I'd be inclined to choose the former - `maxLength` being smaller than 0 could be a symptom of a problem (implementation error) that we wouldn't want to sweep under the carpet. It's also consistent with the way `Substring` itself behaves.

Comment: Correct! Good catch. One small improvement: **Remove the null-checking if statement,** then modify the **return** statement as follows: `return value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));`; will do the same, but much shorter. :-)

Comment: My answer was posted 5 years ago, I'm not sure if C# 6.0 (which introduced the null-safety operator) had been released back then yet ;) Obviously I agree that's the way to go now - as in the accepted answer

Comment: Your answer is still valid, and I agree, null-checking operators where introduced late in C#. The accepted answer does not check for `maxLength < 0`, and I like the fail fast approach you mentioned. So my hint was only for the null-checking. By the way, I am looking for a truncate parameter for the .ToString() method, because I think truncating **after** .ToString() is inefficient. Do you have an idea how that can be achieved? Recall that .ToString() can be invoked on every object or primitive type.

Answer (score 8):

Well, [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/u/23788) already gave [the only improvement for the code in the extension-method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101023) I could find, using [the conditional-member-access operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Aside from that, there's only the methods name. Which is far too long and awkward.
`Truncate` has a nice ring to it, and everybody understands it.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
    {
        return value?.Substring(0, Math.Min(value.Length, maxLength));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Per [Mat's Mug's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101023/36366):

> I'd try to find a name that better indicates that truncation will occur when value is longer than `maxLength`... but `WithMaxLength` isn't a bad name.

I disagree that the method's name is the place to do this.  It's not.  And `WithMaxLength` is a perfectly fine name.

But... that truncation occurs *should* be documented.  I'm not sure what's available exactly for C#, but most all languages have a format for showing in-IDE documentation.

I've been told the C# version of this looks something like this:

```
<summary>
This function does something.
<param name="string">The string to do things with</param>
</summary>
```

We should certainly add this sort of documentation to our method to be clear on *exactly* what happens with the method.  I think any other sort of name for the method itself goes beyond to descriptive and ventures into the realm of *too verbose* (and this is coming from someone who writes Objective-C...).

Comment: I think you're looking for the `<Remarks>` tag.